# How to receive data in android from a embedded device when the phone is locked?

Tags: android, android-wifi

I am receiving data from a embedded device when the phone is in `ON` state. If the phone is locked the connection gets terminated. How to overcome this issue?

Edit:
I used tcp/ip communication. My whole code is in service. I have implemented `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` and `WIFI_MODE_FULL`, but my problem not solved.

Comment: Where are you registering your `BroadcastReceiver` and unregistering it? Posting some code would be help us help you.

Comment: I am not using any BroadcastReceiver in my code